# Gradient descent with momentum

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I am currently making a neural network from scratch and I have gotten it to work with the mnist dataset to get around an 80% accuracy on the test images. It takes a while to get to that point so I'm trying to implement gradient descent with momentum. The current code is:

```
def backProp(self, inputs, correct_output):
    self.outputLayerErrors = np.subtract(self.outputNeurons, correct_output)
    self.hiddenLayerErrors = np.multiply(np.dot(self.secondLayerWeights.T, 

    self.secondLayerBiasesSummations = self.beta*self.secondLayerBiasesSummations + (1-self.beta)*self.outputLayerErrors
    self.secondLayerWeightsSummations = self.beta*self.secondLayerWeightsSummations + (1-self.beta)*np.outer(self.outputLayerErrors, self.secondLayerNeurons)

    self.firstLayerBiasesSummations = self.beta*self.firstLayerBiasesSummations + (1-self.beta)*self.hiddenLayerErrors
    self.firstLayerWeightsSummations = self.beta*self.firstLayerWeightsSummations + (1-self.beta)*np.outer(self.hiddenLayerErrors, inputs)

def change(self):
    self.secondLayerBiases -= self.learningRate * self.secondLayerBiasesSummations
    self.secondLayerWeights -= self.learningRate * self.secondLayerWeightsSummations
    self.firstLayerBiases -= self.learningRate * self.firstLayerBiasesSummations
    self.firstLayerWeights -= self.learningRate * self.firstLayerWeightsSummations
```

beta is set to 0.9 and the learning rate is 0.1. My regular gd runs with a learning rate of 0.0001 but gd with momentum only works with a learning rate of 0.1 and is also worse in terms of accuracy and speed compared to reg gd. Is there anything wrong with my code or math?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add momentum you can record all the gradients to each weight and bias and then add them to the next update. If your way of adding momentum in works, it still seems like updates from the past are all added equally to the current one, the first gradient will still slightly influence an update after 1000 iterations of training.
`self.weights -= self.learningRate*(currentGradient+sum([grad*(self.beta**t) for t, grad in enumerate(reversed(self.pastGradients))])`
This is what momentum usually looks like, where t represents time. You raise *beta* to the power of *t* so old gradients change the update less than recent ones.